# Django ValueError: The view usermanager.views.group_perm didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a News Website. When I try to delete permission from a group the same error is showing. The codes above this function are almost same. But they are working fine.Please Help

**This is my view file**
def group_perm(request, name):

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('my_login')


perm = 0

for i in request.user.groups.all():
    if i.name == "masteruser": perm = 1

if perm == 0:
    error = "Access Denied"
    return render(request, 'back/error.html',{'error': error})


permission = Permission.objects.all()


for group in Group.objects.filter(name=name):
    gperm = group.permissions.all()


    return render(request, 'back/group_perm.html', {'gperm':gperm, 'name':name, 'permission': permission})
```

def group_permission_del(request, gname, name):

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('my_login')


perm = 0
 #"request.user" means current logged User
for i in request.user.groups.all():
    if i.name == "masteruser": perm = 1

if perm == 0:
    error = "Access Denied"
    return render(request, 'back/error.html',{'error': error})



group = Group.objects.get(name=gname)

gperm = Permission.objects.get(codename=name)


group.permissions.remove(gperm)

return redirect('manage_permission')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, your return statement is inside the for loop in group_perm function

> Whitespace is used to denote blocks. like other languages using curly
>   brackets { , }.

```
def group_perm(request, name):
    for i in request.user.groups.all():
        if i.name == "masteruser": perm = 1

    if perm == 0:
        error = "Access Denied"
        return render(request, 'back/error.html', {'error': error})

    permission = Permission.objects.all()

    for group in Group.objects.filter(name=name):
        gperm = group.permissions.all()

    return render(request, 'back/group_perm.html', {'gperm': gperm, 'name': name, 'permission': permission})
```

EDIT:1

> Django ValueError: The view usermanager.views.group_perm didn't return
>   an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

The answer to this error is that your return statement was inside the for loop hence, when you called your function, it returned None. Was it solved by this ?

Now your another function would be like:

```
def group_permission_del(request, gname, name):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('my_login')

    perm = 0
    # "request.user" means current logged User
    for i in request.user.groups.all():
        if i.name == "masteruser": perm = 1

    if perm == 0:
        error = "Access Denied"
        return render(request, 'back/error.html', {'error': error})

    group = Group.objects.get(name=gname)
    gperm = Permission.objects.get(codename=name)
    group.permissions.remove(gperm)

    return redirect('manage_permission')
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gperm' referenced before assignment. This error is showing after changing the code

Comment: Now its working with get(previously filter method) method and group pk(previously with group name). I do not know why it is not working with group name.

Comment: using a debugger, consider checking what values you get in your functions, like what group name do you receive in `def group_perm(...` ?

Comment: yes it is receiving group name. But I changed the code to group by pk. Now its working